# Do NAS home servers allow remote access to files?

Tags: vpn, nas

Do NAS home servers allow you to access files remotely so that a group of people separated by distance can collaborate on a project?

I realize that you can share on a network but documentations for a lot of these machines don't specify remote login.

Comment: Many NAS have a "web browsing" feature that allows you to browse your NAS' contents through a normal web browser. You'd just need to forward the port it's using from your router so it's accessible from outside.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. Many of them have software for VPN, SMB & APF sharing, WebDAV, FTP, Web Server, Mail server. Also, because many of them have their firmware based on UNIX, they can be configured even further as Subversion & Git servers. These are the keywords you should check at a NAS.

From my personal research, the most friendly are Synology and QNAP. I, for one, have a Synology DS212+.

Answer (score 1):

> Do NAS home servers allow you to access files remotely

Some, yes.

> so that a group of people separated by distance can collaborate on a project?

This one's a little trickier. Some do have collaboration capabilities, but usually not in the retail versions. Some companies do offer [solutions](http://pogoplug.com/team) though.

Answer (score 0):

Normally, you can enable a Login through WebDAV or FTP so that users can mount those volumes where ever they are. However, this requires some form of fixed network name, most likely through DynDNS and port forwarding for the protocol you are using.